# mysql query for retrieving multiple values as array

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, group-by

I have two tables user and task as follows:

user:

[image]

task:

[image]

I need to query to get all the user ids of the task id whose user is 2 and the output table should be:
[image]

Can anybody help me with the query? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT 
    t.task_id AS task_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.user_id) AS user_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(u.username) AS user
FROM task t
JOIN user u ON t.user_id = u.id
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM task
   WHERE task.task_id = t.task_id AND task.user_id = 2
)
GROUP BY t.task_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked as expected.